# Split based on two delimiters

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

```
var string1 = 'db.employee.find({"city":"Paris"},{"emp_id":1}'

var result = string.split("."); //split based on .
```

Can anyone help me how to split based on two delimiters (. and [). Since string1 can also be written as

```
//var string1 = 'db["employee"].find({"city":"Paris"},{"emp_id":1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to substitute one of the delimiters for the other (using `replace`) then split on the remaining.